# How can i send e-mail with SendGridAPICliente. Azure Website

Tags: c#, email, azure, sendgrid

I`m trying to send an e-mail with SendGrid but i got some errors. 
I was making this [tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJbos.jpg) but after install SendGrid i cant creat any instance of SendGridMessage.

I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2

```
var test = new SendGirdMessage();
```

I got this error:

> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'SendGridMessage' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Then i already try to use SendGridAPIClient, this i can creat but that aren`t sending the e-mail.
I follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/tree/3a36fab89ab0ee85aa412df07ac1ce3f90dcd49d) With Mail helper class.

Could some one help me to send e-mail from azure?

Comment: You need to include more context. Showing the using statements around the code. If you can get a message sent without Azure in the picture, then you should be able to get it working in Azure as well. I recommend providing an entire snippet that compiles, leaving out your SendGrid API key

Comment: In your update, please don't post a screenshot of the code. Just copy the code here and use the code tags. Also, you really need to provide more information like if there's an error or what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the version 2 of SendGrid to that tutorial. To use this version you have that install the SendGrid C-Sharp 6.3.4 or bellow.
In Package Management Console write:

> Install-Package SendGrid -version 6.3.4